# jQuery replace a subdirectory with prefix and suffix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace a sub directory that has the prefix `/s72` and the suffix `/`. Example:

```
https://www.example.com/dsasdsad/iufnasdadaso/s72/first-picture.img
https://www.example.com/efggvdfb/pothgpbmfkoe/s72-c/second-picture.img
https://www.example.com/jyhjgfdf/rokomvcrvkmw/s72-w222-h888/third-picture.img
https://www.example.com/pokmhfds/qprigmvmspej/s72-c-d/fourth-picture.img
```

I tried to change `/s72/`, `/s72-c/`, `/s72-w222-h888/`, `/s72-c-d/`, and other `/s72` subdirectory with `/w100-h100-c/` using jQuery `.replace()`. If I can't use jQuery `.replace()`, can I replace it in another way?

I have tried:

```
.replace(/\/s72\S+/g,  "/w100-h100-c/")
```

But the result is:

```
https://www.example.com/dsasdsad/iufnasdadaso/w100-h100-c/
https://www.example.com/efggvdfb/pothgpbmfkoe/w100-h100-c/
https://www.example.com/jyhjgfdf/rokomvcrvkmw/w100-h100-c/
https://www.example.com/pokmhfds/qprigmvmspej/w100-h100-c/
```

The filename is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying to match all non-whitespace characters until the end

try this

```
.replace(/\/s72\S*\//g,  "/w100-h100-c/")
```

https://regex101.com/r/UxZDSa/1